# Covariant formulation of weak energy condition

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

The solution to an exercise in general relativity states the following:
[image: exer]
Where T is the energy-momentum tensor. I do not understand how we obtain the transformation for $T_{00}$ to the rest frame of a moving observer. Is this specific to the $T_{00}$ compononent? Or can i transform any tensor in this way?

In the same exercise they do a similar thing here:
[image: weak]

How do we obtain the covariant formulation?
I understand that the formulation coincides with the original one for an observer at rest, i.e. $u=\left(1,0,0,0\right)$ but for me this isn't proof enough.

I'd appreciate any answer, I am probably missing something obvious here,

Tim

**Edit:**

As I continued working on the exercise I stumbled upon a third example of this procedure.

The question is:

[image: img4]

And the answer:

[image: img3]

Again they seem to pull a formula out of their hat, verify that it coincides in one particular case, and then take it as the general, covariant formulation.

Comment: I hope this helps: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/302342/

Comment: Could you please give a reference where you found these solved exercises?

Comment: Thanks javier, unfortunately i'm not quite satisfied with the answer :) and to @magma, these are exercises from my lecture at ETH university, if i give you the links you won't be able to open them..

Answer (score 0):

The tensor formalism is consistent with the principle that physical laws should be invariant disregarding the reference frame. That means that if you formulate a tensorial statement in an easy-to-describe reference frame, e.g. the rest frame, you can generalize the outcome to an arbitrary reference frame.